# Android Studio using API from older and newer Android version

Tags: android, android-studio

While trying to update my Android app to run on Android API level 21 (Lollipop), I've encountered a problem where a method I had used in my app previously is no longer present in the Android source.

Specifically, I use this method from API level 19:

```
android.view.IWindowManager.setInputFilter(android.view.InputFilter)
```

That method was removed completely in API level 21.  I have already located the appropriate method to achieve the same behavior in API level 21, however, I still want my app to run on KitKat devices, so how can I ensure that this is the case?  Is there a way that I can use the new method on Lollipop devices while still using the old method on KitKat devices?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You got an error compilation or a runtime error?

Answer (score 0):

I've learned of a solution that accomplishes what I was looking for.  It is not possible to compile code with the api 19 method under api 21.  However, it is possible to compile under api 19 and use reflection to access the api 21 method.

hrskrs answer will also work, I believe, so long as you can get the code to compile.